# Error: spawn ENOENT in WebStorm file watcher command

Tags: testing, meteor, webstorm, watch, laika

I'm building a Meteor app, and experimenting with testing with [Laika](http://arunoda.github.io/laika/). I'm writing coffeescript in WebStorm 7 on Ubuntu, and trying to use WebStorm's File Watcher feature to re-execute `laika` every time a coffeescript file is changed.

As context, I can run the `laika --ui=bdd` command just fine in my project root, and I can even use the terminal tool in WebStorm to do the same thing. However when I set up a File Watcher, I get the following error every time:

```
/home/oliver/.meteor/tools/latest/bin/laika --ui=bdd -V
[laika log] accepting the following extensions: (js)

  injecting laika...
  loading phantomjs...
  cleaning up injected code


/home/oliver/.meteor/tools/c2a0453c51/lib/node_modules/laika/lib/app.js:130
    if(err) throw err;
                  ^
Error: spawn ENOENT
    at errnoException (child_process.js:988:11)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:779:34)
```

I'm not much of a node guru, and don't really even know how to debug this error, but I'm hoping someone else finds it trivial. Any ideas?

For the record, my config:

[image]

Comment: seems meteor (or phantomjs) can't be started. can you run laika -D to get some verbose logs? it might shed some light on what's happening

Comment: Sadly, `-V` *is* the debug logging, so that's all I'm getting. Adding `-d` yields `NOTICE: if you are looking for debug logs(-d or -D)`.

Answer (score 0):

So it turns out that despite WebStorm saying `Include parent environment variables`, it was actually missing all the good stuff from its `PATH`. I copy pasted my actual terminal `PATH` variable in whole into the Environment variables as:

`PATH=/home/oliver/.meteor/tools/latest/bin:/usr/lib/lightdm/lightdm:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games`

... and it worked! So there's that.

Just as an aside, if you're having similar problems with finding libraries in Laika tests, remember that your tests *use* Meteor, but are not execute *within* the Meteor environment, so whatever libraries you want to use should be `npm install`ed to a `node_modules` directory inside `tests`. Took me a while to figure out.